# Set a Document File in a webform submission programmatically

Tags: webforms

I have writen a PHP class that saves a pdf file programmatically. The class contains a function that returns the Drupal path private://documentA.pdf

I would like to attach the file to a webform submission:

```
$webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load(ID);
$data = $webform_submission->getData();
$data['file_attachment'] = //retrieve the file
$webform_submission->setData($data);
$webform_submission->save();
```

Webform element type of file_attachment is Document file.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To attach the file to a webform submission, you should get the file id first, and then set the `file_attachment` to file id.
Try this out.

```
  $webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load(1);
  $data = $webform_submission->getData();
  // Get the document file object from uri.
  $document = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['uri' => 'private://documentA.pdf']);
  // Get the file Id.
  $doc_id = reset($document)->id();
  // Set the file_attachment to fid. 
  $data['file_attachment'] = $doc_id;
  $webform_submission->setData($data);
  $webform_submission->save();
```